# How to conditionally split and extend inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How do I convert this input:

```
values = ['v1,v2', 'v3']
```

to this output:

```
['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```

---

Attempt without list comprehension that works:

```
values = ['v1,v2', 'v3']
parsed_values = []

for v in values:
    if ',' in v:
        parsed_values.extend(v.split(','))
    else:
        parsed_values.append(v)

print(parsed_values)    # ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```

---

Attempt with list comprehension that does not work:

```
parsed_values = [_ for _ in [v.split(',') if ',' in v else v for v in values]]
# [['v1', 'v2'], 'v3']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't care if there is a comma or not, splitting on it will always give a list you can iterate on

```
values = ['v1,v2', 'v3']
parsed_values = [word for value in values for word in value.split(",")]
print(parsed_values)
# ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
values = ["v1,v2", "v3"]

values = ",".join(values).split(",")
print(values)
```

Prints:

```
['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
```